# Outlook Rules - Two almost identical rules, one works the other does not

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, rules

I'm going crazy.

Company recently switched to Office365 and I had to redo some rules to be server-side as before they were client-side and I was having issues with my machine taking like an hour to sort email when I first booted it up (now it's all done at night when I'm not logged in).

Anyway, I have basically two sets of rules for each situation:

Rule Type #1: Takes the message and puts it into a folder. It doesn't mark it read or delete it or anything...the second you add one of those options it makes the rule client-side only which won't run at night when I'm not logged in...only when my Outlook client is open.

Rule Type #2: I have a duplicate set of rules which DON'T move the emails to folders but instead mark them as read and permanently deletes them. These rules I run manually once or twice a week.

---

Now, my issue is that I have ONE #2 rule...one SINGLE rule...that refuses to function. The first version of it will successfully sort the emails from this one particular sender but the 2nd rule will NOT mark as read or permanently delete from this particular sender. I have a feeling it's something with the sender so I've tried using the short group name as well as the full on email (with the @.com). I have like 10 other sets of rules setup the same way (from other senders or groups).

Anyone have any ideas? All other rules work great...except for this one where the 2nd half of it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to share that after searching through the web, I did end up finding a solution that seems to work for this particular 'group'. It's on Superuser too boot!

[Exchange mail rule triggering on a From address that is a public group](https://superuser.com/questions/885577/exchange-mail-rule-triggering-on-a-from-address-that-is-a-public-group)

Setting the rule to check for 'specific words in the sender's address' instead of 'from people or public group' seemed to do the trick.

Phew! Now time to monitor for a few days.