# Microsoft Outlook - rules for groups affecting mails coming from individual

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I am running outlook 2016.

I have a set a number of rules to move messages as and when they come to inbox.

For examples I receive mails from an distribution list and i have created a rule to move it to a folder, let us say "support" folder. The rule works perfectly. However there is one person who is part of this distribution list and sends mail to me. Issue is that even mails sent from his ID directly to me also moves to the support folder.

How to rectify this ? Or is there a different way to handle such mails ?

Simha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exchange mail rule triggering on a From address that is a public group](https://superuser.com/questions/885577/exchange-mail-rule-triggering-on-a-from-address-that-is-a-public-group)

Comment: The second-last paragraph in the accepted answer to that question has the same details as Steve Fan's: 
Additionally, in Outlook 2013 (I believe that's the first version with it) they've added a new rule that's very similar to the message Headers rule, only it's "with specific words in the sender's address".

Answer (score 9):

This is the expected behavior. The rule with "From group" condition will apply to all messages received from any member of the group.

To work around this, edit the rule condition to 'with specific words in the sender's address', click 'specific words' and add the address of your group.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this problem for a long time and just now discovered the reason why. This is not the expected behaviour (or at least in my opinion, it shouldn't be unless you specifically add to the rule that you want the whole group to fall in the filter, which is unfortunately not possible at the moment as far as I know. The odds are you don't even know that that e-mail is a group)

**My way to solve this was to create the rule through Outlook desktop application instead of outlook.com**

It seems the web app parses the e-mail into some sort of ID and detects it is a group and automatically apply the rule to the whole group.

Creating the rule in the desktop app, you can see the difference right away. It will show you the exact e-mail address instead of the group alias the web version shows. The rule will be applied to the server so you don't need to worry about having to use the desktop version just so the rules are applied. You only need to open it to create the rules.

About what is expected behaviour or not, I would assume the expected behaviour is the one from the desktop version as it came first. But that's just my opinion.

**Edit:** Later on I had issues with these again. Creating some rules through Desktop and some through Web caused my rules list to be corrupted from time to time, so I decided to completely ignore the existence of the Desktop application and now I only create rules in the Web version.

The problem with this is that we get back to OP's problem, to which I would suggest to go around this by frequently checking these folders and when you see somebody that shouldn't be there, add that e-mail as an exception to the rule.