# Outlook 2016 mail rule not triggering for condition "from people or public group" for any value except myself

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, rules

This question may be related to
[Exchange mail rule triggering on a From address that is a public group](https://superuser.com/questions/885577/exchange-mail-rule-triggering-on-a-from-address-that-is-a-public-group) but not's quite the same story.

I'm setting up `mail rules` in `Outlook 2016`. I only have access to the client, which is how I'm setting up mail rules. I don't have access to the Exchange servers. I believe the configuration is Office 365, meaning this is the cloud version of Outlook/Office.

I'm encountering an issue with the condition of *from people or public group* where the rule will not fire with anybody selected except myself. Let's say my name is *John Smith*. My email is *johnsmith@example.com*. I specify *John Smith* for this condition. The action is play Windows notification sound. Works like a charm.

Say I want to play the sound for emails sent by *Jane Dane*. I modify the earlier rule such that now the condition is *from Jane Dane*, instead of *from John Smith*. Simple, right. Well, it doesn't work. Nothing happens.

I can't find any documentation on how to enable debugging for mail rule tracing. I turned on Outlook logging but none of the files have any data pertaining to mail rules. If I could couple `Outlook` with `VS` somehow and break on whatever code handles mail rules, that'd be fantastic. Then I can analyze precisely what's happening. At the moment, I'm working with my eyes closed here.

Has anyone else encountered this issue before? Anyone have any ideas on how to output a detailed trace for mail rules?

Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind Outlook rules are hierarchical when using @Perry's answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the earlier rule, what if we create a new one?

What’s the rule description? When creating rules, please also select the condition “stop processing more rules” to avoid rule conflicts.

[image]

It could also indicate a corruption in the send/receive settings file (srs-file) of Outlook.

Resetting the send/receive settings can be achieved by renaming the srs-file of your profile to `.old`.

You can find the srs-file for your mail profile in: `%AppData%\Microsoft\Outlook`

If issue still persists, recreate .ost files to see the results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried modifying a rule. I tried creating a new rule. Makes no difference, unfortunately. I keep the rule simple for this test. Apply to message received from `people or public group` of *Jane Smith* and play sound if true. I added stop processing more rules, as well. Made no difference. I'll give the srs-file reset and the .ost file re-create a shot and let you know the outcome. Thank you for the help. Kind-of odd that mail rules cannot be debugged down to the code level. And if they can, I haven't found a way yet.

Comment: OK, so I renamed the srs-file and Outlook created a new one. I'm not 100% sure if it helped or it's a coincidence but I see now individual `People` are triggered in the *from* condition. `Public Groups`, however, are still an issue and it may be a misunderstanding on my part. Name is *testsharedmailbox* and e-mail is *testsharedmailbox@example.com*. I want the rule to fire on emails sent from that shared email address. Does `from` look up *testsharedmailbox@example.com* or the individuals in said group? If it's the latter, that'd would explain why the rule doesn't fire. Thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: I should also add the people and groups I reference are from the `Global Address List`, which I have no control over, with respect to adding, removing, modifying. I have no write permissions, basically.

Comment: add the addresses from Global Address List work?